# I want to know how to block traffic to my sub domains

Tags: .htaccess, firewall, cloudflare

My domain is example.co.uk    and my sub domain is app.example.co.uk

I would like to know. How can I block all the traffic to my sub domain except from India & UK.
Whether it can be done by cloudflare firewall rules or workers?

If not. Then how can i block ?
help me out this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example here
https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/known-issues-and-faq#how-do-i-create-an-exception-to-exclude-certain-requests-from-being-blocked-or-challenged

In your case, the following rule may work

[image]

Comment: Thank You really. It helps me out instantly

Comment: I hope. This doesn't affect good google bots crawlers from the united states. I have allowed verified bots in Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you review the geo blocking technology. it works based on the user's location but it can be circumvented with vpn.